# Can't Get Json to display in ag Grid just says loading

Tags: json, angular, go, ag-grid

Using various example I have found on the web I pieced together a simple web app.  However although AG Grid (the grid I have chosen to display the data works with the data source provided, it does not work with my own data source which was created using a web service written in Go.

Angular code...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.rowData = this.http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ly7d1'); 
}
```

This works correctly showing the data on the grid. but when i redirect it to me Go generated data using the following...

```
ngOnInit() {   
  this.rowData = this.http.get('http://localhost:10000/all');
}
```

This grid just says loading...

if I test either link in the browser I get the exact same data formatted in the exact same way...

```
[{"make":"Toyota","model":"Celica","price":35000},{"make":"Ford","model":"Mondeo","price":32000},{"make":"Porsche","model":"Boxter","price":72000},{"make":"Toyota","model":"Celica","price":35000},{"make":"Ford","model":"Mondeo","price":32000},{"make":"Porsche","model":"Boxter","price":72000},{"make":"Toyota","model":"Celica","price":35000},{"make":"Ford","model":"Mondeo","price":32000},{"make":"Porsche","model":"Boxter","price":72000},{"make":"Toyota","model":"Celica","price":35000},{"make":"Ford","model":"Mondeo","price":32000},{"make":"Porsche","model":"Boxter","price":72000}]
```

Here is the link to the Json:

https://api.myjson.com/bins/ly7d1

I am running both my angular app and the go app on the same machine but there are different services and using different ports...

I could include the Go code but I do not see how relevant it is as the data displays correctly in a browser.

tried to include only the stuff that is relevant but if I have missed something please let me know and I can upload.

HTML Code...

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>


    <button (click)="onBtExport()">Export to CSV</button>

    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="rowData | async"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      rowSelection="multiple"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Expected Output...

[image: AG Grid display]

Go web service code...

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// Article - Our struct for all articles
type Article struct {

    Make string `json:"make"`
    Model   string `json:"model"`
    Price int32 `json:"price"`
}

type Articles []Article

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}

func returnAllArticles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    articles := Articles{
        Article{Make: "Toyota", Model: "Celica", Price: 35000},
        Article{Make: "Ford", Model: "Mondeo", Price: 32000},
        Article{Make: "Porsche", Model: "Boxter", Price: 72000},
        Article{Make: "Toyota", Model: "Celica", Price: 35000},
        Article{Make: "Ford", Model: "Mondeo", Price: 32000},
        Article{Make: "Porsche", Model: "Boxter", Price: 72000},
        Article{Make: "Toyota", Model: "Celica", Price: 35000},
        Article{Make: "Ford", Model: "Mondeo", Price: 32000},
        Article{Make: "Porsche", Model: "Boxter", Price: 72000},
        Article{Make: "Toyota", Model: "Celica", Price: 35000},
        Article{Make: "Ford", Model: "Mondeo", Price: 32000},
        Article{Make: "Porsche", Model: "Boxter", Price: 72000},
    }
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAllArticles")

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(articles)
}



type Tag struct {
    JN   string    `json:"jobno"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
}

func returnSingleArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["id"]
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Key: "+key)
}

func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", homePage)

    myRouter.HandleFunc("/all", returnAllArticles)  
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000", myRouter))
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

Update
I have now tried the following...
Completely rewrote the site and service on my Macbook 
tried using different ports on the server and the client
tried running the server on a different machine
disabled all firewalls

none of this makes any difference.

Comment: HTML Code will be needed and expected output

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console? This might be a CORS issue.

Comment: no Errors, I just built the go app and put on a another PC, I am still able to access through the bowser but still not the angular app

Comment: @user3755946 Does a http request get send? Maybe post an image of your network tab.

Comment: I will check this today

Comment: I download an http tool "fiddler" and it come up with a red cross on the http request saying it was aborted by the client or the server.

Comment: @user3755946 the developer tools of your browser should be enough to help you determine the cause of your error. Do you know how to use these? Please post an image of your browsers debug console and network tab, when the request is made! I still think this is a CORS issue and your Go server isn't configured correctly or probably doesn't handle the preflight `http options` requests.

Comment: I have added the Go Webservice code

Comment: I do not know how to use the dev tools I come from a win forms environment, I am using the dev tools now.

Comment: you were right about cors issue zone.js:3243 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:10000/all' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the data because your browser blocks cross-origin HTTP request from `http://localhost:4200` to `http://localhost:10000/all` for security reasons. Your Go server has to be able to handle preflight `OPTIONS` requests and send the right [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers in the response.

Use `gorilla/handlers` OR `rs/cors` to enable CORS support.

```
import (
    "net/http"   
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/rs/cors"          
)

func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", homePage) 
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/all", returnAllArticles)

    // ----- OPTION 1 ----- Use rs/cors
    corsOptions := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"},
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"}, // instead of '*' you can add the urls you want to allow e.g. 'http://localhost:4200'          
        AllowedMethods: []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodDelete, http.MethodOptions, http.MethodHead}
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000", corsOptions.Handler(myRouter))
    // --------------------------------


    // ----- OPTION 2 ----- Use gorilla/handlers
    corsHeaders := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"})
    corsOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    corsMethods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000", handlers.CORS(corsHeaders, corsOrigins, corsMethods)(myRouter)))
    // --------------------------------
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

Comment: Did you use the current version? I edited the answer a couple of times.

Comment: yes I seen that i did use the current version, same error..Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:10000/all' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: noticed if i stop the go service i get the same error could it also be a client issue?

Comment: Are you sure you call `http://localhost:10000/all` with the `http://`? Maybe your missing `http://` in your request url. Otherwise please add screenshots of the errors you get in the browsers developer console and the browsers developer network tab to your question.

Comment: that is now after i made the changes i commented out the wrong line off code, thanks for you help.