# How to add header on angular 8 service for cors control

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my service

```
export class user {
    apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/'

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

    getUser() {
     return this._http.get(this.apiUrl + `user`, {});
}
```

how to add a header for `CORS` control ?

Comment: `CORS` is server side

Comment: Your Api has to provide `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers with the response.

Comment: @fridoo exemple please ?

Comment: @HamzaBouallegue You have to search for how to provide these headers with the server you're using. For a Go server it can look like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55904938/9423231. General information about CORS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/9423231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its too  late but for others, the only way to to disable/enable CORS in Angular is use proxy configure as your angular option.

for example you can put `proxy.json` into  `assets` folder and fill it as below contents:

`assets/proxy.json` :

```
{
    "/api/v1/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
    }
}
```

and change your `serve/build` with below code in `angular.json` file :

```
"architect": {
    "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {
                "browserTarget": "your-project-name:build",
                "proxyConfig": "assets/proxy.json"
            },
          }
}
```

NOTE: don't forget to enable CORS header in your server side project.